# Wordpress custom query by archive title

Tags: wp-query, ajax, tags, archives

I'm using Ajax to load more posts on my theme, it works perfectly on the homepage but when I go with an archive (tags / category), it loads all the posts just like in the homepage.

```
if( is_tag() )
{
    $cat = single_tag_title('', false);
}
else if( is_category() )
{
    $cat = single_cat_title('', false);
}

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'tag'            => $cat,
    'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
    'category_name'  => $cat,
    'offset'         => $offset,
);
```

Thanks beforehand and have a good day !

Comment: Please show your complete code in an [edit]—in the best case, something reproducible. Above is just arguments for some query I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I have just made this on a rush but would you please try this :

```
<?php 
 if( is_tag() ){
   $tag = single_tag_title('', false);
 }else{
   $tag='';
 }
if( is_category() ){
 $cat = single_cat_title('', false);
}else{
  $cat ='';
}

$args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'post',
  'post_status'    => 'publish',
  'tag'            => $tag,
  'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
  'category_name'  => $cat,
  'offset'         => $offset,
);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mohamed, but the problem remains, the query loads all the posts regarding which page I'm in.

Comment: Again to be more specific.. you want to make a query that loads tag related posts if you are into a tag archive and loads category related post if I you are into category.. because I don't think you want this .. this is wordpress default i